# Laravel 8 - How to use where conditions for relation's column

Tags: laravel, model, where-clause, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

hello friends can you help me to get the contents of $filter? I want to run where which is where the target column is in the relation array

```
    $filter = $request->get('Biogear');
    $data = DetailBarang::with(['barang' => function ($q) use ($filter) {
        $q->where('brand', '=', $filter);
    }])->get();
    return response()->json($data);
```

Comment: You can use `whereHas` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships,
`with` will return `null` base on the filter but it will not be filtered out, so putting your $filter to whereHas will filter the list if `barang` returns null.

Comment: @Forbidden thanks for your response. I've tried what you recommend, but I still get the error.. can you give me a sample code. thank you very much for you

Comment: "but I still get the error" ... what error?

Comment: hallo @lagbox thank you for response, so I get an error like this `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::whereHas(): Argument #2 ($callback) must be of type ?Closure, string given, called in D:\Project\inventory-web\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php on line 23`

Comment: I've tried this but there's an error I'm getting ` $dimensions = DetailBarang::query()
            ->with('barang')
            ->whereHas('barang',  function ($query) use ($filter) {
                return $query->where('brand', 'LIKE', '%' . $filter . '%');
            })
            ->first()
            ->barang()
            ->get(); `

Comment: I guess the `whereHas` method is a void.
it should be
`whereHas('barang', function ($q) use ($filter) {
   $q->where('brand', 'like', '%'.$filter.'%');
})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
    $filter = $request->get('Biogear');
    $data = DetailBarang::with('barang')->whereHas('barang',function (Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $q) use ($filter) {
        $q->where('brand', '=', $filter);
    })->get();

    return response()->json($data);
```

Comment: hallo @Bhargav Ragani.. where do you get ] in your code before get();

Comment: edited my answer there is no need of ]

Comment: Big thank's for you everyone who has responded to my question...... i have found the answer and it works.. again, i am very grateful. I hope you are all healthy always